# Using Exchange Web Services(EWS) how I can determine admin user?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS OAuth for authentication Office 365 users, but sometime I need to verify provided office 365 user is admin or not. I checked Microsoft Graph API for the same but I need to validate user is admin or not using EWS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred many Microsoft documents and asked same question on Microsoft community. I get below answer from the Microsoft expert.

There's nothing in EWS that covers that, use the Graph API